# understanding postgresql regex in query

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
    SELECT substring(fld_path || fld_filename FROM '#\"%#\".zip$' for '#') AS file
FROM tbl_files
```

Im working on someone elses code and getting unexpected behaviour and cant work out what this means. havent done much regular expression stuff.

Can anyone tell me what this query is returning? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html
The substring function with three parameters, substring(string from pattern for escape-character), provides extraction of a substring that matches an SQL regular expression pattern. 
As with SIMILAR TO, the specified pattern must match the entire data string, or else the function fails and returns null. 
To indicate the part of the pattern that should be returned on success, the pattern must contain two occurrences of the escape character followed by a double quote ("). 
The text matching the portion of the pattern between these markers is returned.

Some examples, with #" delimiting the return string:

```
substring('foobar' from '%#"o_b#"%' for '#')   oob
substring('foobar' from '#"o_b#"%' for '#')    NULL
```

Ithink you shold remove the \ in the patten.

```
digoal=# select substring('abcdefg' from '#\"%#\"g%' for '#');
 substring 
-----------

(1 row)

digoal=# select substring('abcdefg' from '#"%#"g%' for '#');
 substring 
-----------
 abcdef
(1 row)
```

Comment: thanks that helps understand it alright and behaves as you describe it